# What does the error "Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point." mean

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, mstest, xunit.net

I was troubleshooting steps I could find in relation to an IIS 502.5 error with no success.

In desperation I tried starting over using dotnet publish from the command line and got a build error telling me there were 2 entry points in the application and that I needed to "Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point."  First I checked my solution to verify that there is only 1 Main() method in the project. Even though the target namespace is specified in the csproj file, I leave no stone unturned and attempt to run dotnet build with a /main switch only to be told that /main is an unknown switch.

So...what is that error message is telling me and where might I look next to discover what I am certain will be an embarrassing developer error.

Comment: Are you trying to solve your IIS hosting issue or want an explanation of the /main (+ `dotnet build`) issue? seems like two distinct questions

Comment: Both, but I rewrote this question and decoupled it from IIS.

Answer (score 1):

In desperation I went back over the commits I had made since I last was able to run the app successfully and I noticed I had upgraded my test SDK library from 15.3.0 to 15.5.0.  Since I had read several issues regarding MSTest injecting a program main into the test project, so I reverting to version 15.3.0 and my program is now fine in development again. I am not certain what changed between the two versions because Andrew Lock in [this blog post](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/) describes the problem in detail with version 15.3.0.  I don't know why I was ok with version 15.3.0.

Still didn't solve my problem with the 502.5 error in IIS

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found out, the test SDK automatically generates an additional code file to make sure that there is a main method in test ""libraries"" (which are then made an application) - this is purely to make use of build logic that is only triggered for applications to create a "runnable" output even though the main method is never called and only side effects of creating an applications are used by the test runner.

The error about the `/main` parameter is generated by the compiler. When invoking the `csc.exe` compiler directly, this is the parameter to use when specifying which main method to use if there are multiple options.

However, the build tooling that is used to build project files (`.csproj`) uses msbuild logic which then invokes the compiler. This msbuild tooling will only understand msbuild-specific parameters and not parameters of `csc`. Unfortunately, the error message was authored under the assumption that the `csc` command line host was used to perform the compilation.

MSBuild uses the `StartupObject` property to pass this configuration option to the compiler. So one could either specify it inside the csproj file (assuming a static `MyLib.AlternativeProgram.Main()` method):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartupObject>MyLib.AlternativeProgram</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or specify it as arguments to commands that understand the msbuild syntax for setting properties:

```
$ dotnet build /p:StartupObject=MyLib.AlternativeProgram

> msbuild.exe /p:StartupObject=MyLib.AlternativeProgram
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.  I don't have time this week to upgrade to 15.5 again and test your solution.  But I will find the time next week and let you know how I fare.

Comment: I don't think this is going to solve any problem, it just explains what the error means and how the `/main` argument is controlled in this case. (that's the danger of mixing questions..)